# p5.js sketch: I want to use another sketch as an animated background

Tags: p5.js

I have created a p5.js sketch similar to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk&t=812s

I want to give it an animated "background" which would be another p5.js sketch (the goal is to make a sketch that is like a starry sky").

I have only completed the terrain generation, and I wanted to know if it was even possible to do what I have in mind

Answer (score 1):

Ok! So my issue was, whenever I used noFill() to give the background no color, the animation would duplicaate/stgger. The previous frame did not erase, thus gave a strange effect.

I used: background(0, 0)

Which gave the sketch the clear background I was looking for, thus allowing me to show one sketch below the other